# Is there anyway to use a shape or mesh as a mask?

Tags: modeling, animation, materials, shaders

I saw a tutorial on making a "sky box" or "Sky dome" and I was wondering if this can be done in any other shape like a humanoid mesh.

Alternatively: im trying to figure out out how to put a nebula/space or Galaxy in a human shape so when it moves , so does the image like a parallax effect or a window.

My other best guess would be using some kind of projection mapping?

Comment: Could you show some example? Seems like simple Texture Coordinates > Camera should do the trick, but I'm not sure what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I agree with @cgslav, it is hard to understand what you're asking. Could you maybe explain a little further or maybe even add images of the desired effect? That way people will know exactly what you want and if their answer answers your question, so they won't hesitate posting it and you will get more high quality answers.

Comment: A sky box is just what is visible beyond everything else, that is what the world background material is for. For your nebula, if you use a texture coordinates node and connect the camera or window output, the texture will stay still as you nebula moves.